# Open .fbx-file with procedural materials in Xcode (scene kit)

Tags: ios, xcode, textures, scenekit

I am new to 3d models and downloaded a 3d model of a car, that I want to use in Scene Kit.

The model contains a couple of .png-textures, however, most of the textures are procedural materials, which means they do not come with picture-files. When I open the .fbx-file in Blender, the whole car is shown properly (with the right textures).

How is it possible, to open such a model in Xcode to use it in Scene Kit?

When I just convert it to .obj-Format and open it, it only has single Colors, without any textures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add several light object to your scene.
cause blender's light is different from scene's, even your fbx file contains some lights, but scenekit doesn't render them right.